# Commutating operators and tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products

I have this lecture slides about commutators and tensor products, but there is one part that I don't understand:

> The operators $1 \otimes H_2$ and $H_1 \otimes 1$ are commuting operators on the tensor product $E_1 \otimes E_2$ and their sum $H := 1 \otimes H_2 + H_1 \otimes 1$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda^1_j + \lambda^2_k$ with the eigenvectors $e^1_j \otimes e^2_k$.

First of all, what is $1$? is it a matrix full with ones?

Secondly, what does it mean, commuting operators **on** the tensor product?

I also don't really understand the last part of the sentence, but I don't even know how to formulate a question about this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably $E_1,E_2$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and we have operators $H_i  : E_i \to E_i$. By $1$, one means the identity on the $E_i$. Then we get operators $1 \otimes H_2 : E_1 \otimes E_2 \to E_1 \otimes E_2$ induced by $x \otimes y \mapsto x \otimes H_2(y)$ and similarly for $H_1 \otimes 1$. Then $H$ is an operator on $H_1 \otimes H_2$.
If $1 \otimes H_2$ and $H_1 \otimes 1$ commute, this means in particular that $x \otimes H_2(y) = H_1(x) \otimes y$, for all $x \in E_1$ and $y \in E_2$.

Answer (score 2):

1 is the identity operator, or a matrix with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere. Commuting operators A and B simply means that AB = BA, and ON the tensor product means that this tensor product is the domain and the range of the operators, that is A is a function taking an element of the tensor product as its argument and producing another element of that tensor product. (Note that by tensor product I mean a space here, the term also refers to elements of that space)

If for an operator A there exists a non-zero vector v and a number a such that A(v) = av, then v is said to be an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue a.

Comment: ok, I only knew the notation 'I' for the identity operator. Could you elaborate on what it means that the tensor product is the domain of the operators? I understand the rest, thanks.